# Align a column with CSS

Tags: html, css, web

I want to align columns in a table based on a class on the header.
For example, if I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th class="price">Price</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ....
    </tbody>
<table>
```

I know I can use :nth-of-type but sometimes the column will be the 2th, other time will be the 5th and in some places I'll have several columns in the same table align to the right.

Is there a way to accomplish that?
I don't need to support legacy browsers, not even Internet Explorer 9 (if is works on chrome and/or firefox is enough for me)

Just for clarification, I want to align the text in the columns that are in the body associated with the column at the head

Comment: You mean the text-alignment? Just do: `th.price { text-align:right; }`

Comment: yes, I mean text align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot style table cells so that styling depends on a `class` attribute on a column header `th`. There is nothing in CSS that connects cells that way.

The most robust way to align a column is to generate `class` attributes on each cell in it. Well, technically, using the HTML `align` attribute is even more robust.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As commented below this only works with a few properties. Text-align isn't included.

Put this in your CSS:

```
col.price { text-align:right; }
```

And your HTML:

```
<table>
  <col />
  <col class="price" />
  <tr>
    <td>First TD of first TR</td>
    <td>9,95</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First TD of second TR</td>
    <td>4,85</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Reference:
http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/columns.html

Comment: I think OP meant the whole column, not only the th.

Comment: The cited page says: “W3C specifies that only a few declarations may be used on columns: border, background, width and visibility. Exception: IE7 and lower allow all declarations.” So setting `text-align` does not work, except on non-conforming browsers. You can see this by testing with some data where alignment makes a difference, e.g. with one of the numbers having more digits than the other.